# Python subprocess getting killed. Probably because of memory issue. How to resolve this?

Tags: python, subprocess, bioinformatics

I's using python subprocess module to run an unix command inside my python code. I just want to check if a specific search term is present in the same line in input file (The input file size is 1.8 GB). Here is the python code that I wrote. However, when I execute this program, my python code is getting killed.

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.Popen(['zcat', '/home/user/input_data/sample_ID/file_name.gvcf.gz', '|', 'grep', '-w', 'chr7', '|', 'grep', '-w', '87509329'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
print(output)
```

`Killed`

If I run this same command in my terminal, I'm able to get the result correctly. Here is the result that I got while running in terminal

```
zcat file_name.gvcf.gz | grep -w "chr7" | grep -w "87509329"
chr7    87509329    .   A   .   .   .   DP=29   GT:AD:DP:ICNT:RGQ:SPL   0/0:99:29:127,1,1,0,0,0,0,0:81:0,81,255`
```

I assume because of some memory issue, my python code is getting killed. Could anyone please guide me how I can resolve this issue?

I just want to check if the two patterns "chr7" and "87509329" are present in the same line in the input file without uncompressing it.

Comment: You are trying to use pipes in the command, that's something that is processed by a shell., but it cannot be understood by the `zcat` command, which is the image loaded by Popen. Try giving the command as a string and setting `shell=True'.

Comment: Using `shell=True` is not the best practice, as it opens a big attack surface, but it could be a quick workaround for a one-time execution.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `zgrep` to avoid the issues pointed out by @Poshi.

Try this in your Terminal:

```
zgrep -Ew "chr7.*87509329|87509329.*chr7" file_name.gvcf.gz
```

It is looking for either pattern1 followed by pattern2, or pattern2 followed by pattern1 - this is called an *"alternation"* extended regex and is why there is a `-E` and a pipe (`|`) between the two alternations.